# Permissions for Pipelines triggered by another Pipeline

Tags: security, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

We have several Build/CI pipelines that trigger on a completion of a Pull Request and several Deployment/CD pipelines that trigger when those Build/CI pipelines complete.
So, Pull Request triggers CI, CI triggers CD.

We'd like to restrict the permissions on the CD pipeline runs (since they deploy into production) to Read Only. I.e. a User who completed the Pull Request shouldn't be able to cancel/retry stages that are related to production.

We changed the permissions via "Manage Security" button on the folder containing the CD Pipelines and removed all but "View build pipeline" and "View Build" permissions for selected users.

This has resulted in User having read only access to the pipeline runs **except** in the case where they were the trigger of the CI (aka it was their Pull Request). They find each other's runs read only but they still have access to their own runs.

This is not what we want, as we'd like to make every run (regardless who triggered the pipeline).

Note: the permission clearly works to some extent given they see each others runs read only - and they cannot queue new runs (except via the PR>CI>CD triggers).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this official doc [Pipeline permissions reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/policies/permissions?view=azure-devops#pipeline-permissions-reference):

- Queue builds: Can queue new builds
- Stop builds: Can stop builds queued by other team members or by the system.

If you set the above two permissions to deny, the user will not have permissions to rerun/cancel other user's builds but can still manage their own builds.

Currently there is no such permission to restrict managing your own builds. If you want such a permission, you can submit a feature request on: [Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/report?space=21&entry=suggestion). Voting helps increase the priority of the issue by consolidating customer impact under one feedback. Besides, I noticed that there is already a [feature request](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Disable-Rerun-failed-jobs-and-Rerun-a/10482974?sort=newest&ftype=idea) asking for disabling "Rerun failed jobs" and "Rerun all jobs" button, you can follow it and add some comments if you want such a feature.

Comment: Thank you, I've up voted the feature request.

I suppose the interesting point is the team member did not actually queue the pipeline themselves (they don't have access to) but it was a trigger from another pipeline.  So I would expect the pipeline to be "queued by the system" for security purposes?

Comment: @Sean Brotherton, although the CD-pipeline is not directly triggered by the user, the PR is triggered by this user. If you run this REST API [Builds - Get](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/builds/get?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1), you can see the `requestedFor` is the user who triggers the PR. `requestedFor` is the identity on whose behalf the build was queued. So that the user can rerun/cancel the CD-build triggered by CI-build which triggered by his PR.